# Reading a binary file into a string

Tags: java, android, file, stream, io

It must be obvious, but I can't figure it out. 
I spent almost a whole day for this.
I'll gladly buy a beer to someone who can lighten me.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)));
dataInputStream.readFully(bytes);           
dataInputStream.close();            
return new String(bytes);
```

This is my code.
I see that the byte array size is not OK, but I can't figure out the right size.
Besides that the contents are not also incorrect.
It seems that only the text characters are OK.

It seems get out the data from a binary file is a real pain, I'm really depressed.

One more thing: the file contents are not text, it can be anything like a picture, video, or pdf.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're reading a binary file you should *not* try to treat it as if it were encoded text. It's inappropriate to convert it to a string like this - you should keep it as a byte array. If you *really* need it as text, you should use base64 or hex to represent the binary data - other approaches are likely to lose data.

If `readFully` returned without an exception, that shows it's read as much data as you requested, which should be the whole file. You've managed to get the data from a binary file fairly easily (although the `close()` call should be in a finally block) - it's only converting it to text which is a bad idea.

Comment: The background: 
I need to post the file data to the a server in base64 encoded format.

What I did is: I encoded the resulted String to Base64 which is insane.

Furthermore now I discovered that I can solve the whole story with one function: Base64.encodeFromFile(filePath) (3rd party base64 by Robert Harder because target is SDK 4)

Now all three solutions including Pablo's resulting the same file.
Which is sadly still not ok beacuse the resulting file size is almost 10 times bigger than the original. But that's another story.

Comment: OK I checked, that problem is somewhere in the network layer.
The resulting base64 encoded string is correct.

Answer (score -2):

As Jon Skeet told you (and you should always listen someone with 347k!), if it is not a text, do not save it in a string and keep it as a byte array. Also, try commons-io and use its helper classes.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
InputStream is  = null;
byte[] bytes = null;
try{
    bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
}finally{
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is)
}
```

Comment: IOUtils is from which package...?

Comment: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils ... also, your IDE should help you find the package

Comment: `InputStream is` is never set to anything - did you mean to set it to `FileInputStream(file)` ?